# Securely data transmission in a consumer application through public IP

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am planning to make a consumer based application on iPhone that will frequently use the webservices for displaying the data.
My requirement is to make the data to flow through the air securely. I mean to say that using https web service will secure the data but can we do this on a public IP?

To be more clear suppose my server is placed in public IP , how can I exchange data securely either using web services or any other means of data transport?

Regards.
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [TSL/SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).